# Is the first axiom of groups redundant?

Tags: group-theory

Group axioms are:
$$(a\circ b)\circ c = a\circ (b\circ c)
\\e\circ a=a\circ e=a\\
a\circ a^{-1}=a^{-1}\circ a=e$$

For example if I have some Cayley table, then only by axioms 2 and 3,
$$\\$$ I can do this prove for associativity?
$$
a\circ (b\circ c)=(a\circ b)\circ c\\
a^{-1}a\circ (b\circ c)=a^{-1}(a\circ b)\circ c\\
b\circ c=a^{-1}(a\circ b)\circ c\\
b\circ cc^{-1}=a^{-1}(a\circ b)\circ cc^{-1}\\
b=a^{-1}(a\circ b)\\
ab=aa^{-1}(a\circ b)\\
a\circ b= a\circ b
$$

Without the need to check every triple?

Comment: Why is it that $a^{-1}\circ (a\circ (b\circ c))=(a^{-1}\circ a)\circ (b\circ c)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it doesn't imply this. You would have to start from $a\cdot b=a\cdot b$ and conclude $b=a^{-1}\cdot (a\cdot b)$. However the LHS is not $b$ but just $a^{-1}\cdot (a\cdot b)$ again. You cannot do it because it would assume associativity, i.e.,
$$
a^{-1}\cdot (a\cdot b)=(a\cdot a^{-1})\cdot b=e\cdot b=b
$$